# How to find the potential difference between two charged spheres?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage

[image]

*Here, the blue sphere (positively charged with $+Q$ charge) is at a lower potential and the pink sphere (positively charged with $+Q$ charge) is at a higher potential, even though they are equally positively charged, as the radius of the pink sphere is smaller.*

TLDR: the blue sphere is at a lower potential and the pink sphere is at a higher potential

---

Suppose the electric potential of the blue ball, $V_{\text{blue}}=5\,\text V$, and the electric potential of the pink ball, $V_{\text{pink}}=10\,\text{V}$. Now, is the potential difference between the two balls

$$V_{\text{blue}}-V_{\text{pink}}=-5\text{V}$$

or

$$V_{\text{pink}}-V_{\text{blue}}=5\,\text{V}$$

?

Comment: The two equations are algebraically equivalent, so you when you state one of them the other is automatically implied. Maybe you prefer stating the positive difference, but that's really just a convention/preference...

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/10324/312838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a - b = c$ then it implies $b-a = -c$ so both of your propositions are equivalently correct.

Comment: So, both -5V and +5V can be stated as the potential difference between the pink and the blue spheres?

Comment: Yes, It's like when you have a 5V battery. There are 5V from the plus sign to the minus sign on the battery, but there are -5V from the minus sign to the plus sign.